# Trouble sending a MAPI message

Tags: c++, send, mapi

I am trying to send a message using Extended MAPI, but keep getting an E_ACCESSDENIED error. I am using a C# class which invokes a cpp dll. I am able to check mail and delete messages, but not send. Below is the C# I use to create the message:

```
using (MAPIMessage message = new MAPIMessage())
{
   if (message.Create(this))
   {
      message.SetSender(send.SenderName, send.SenderAddress);
      message.SetSubject(send.Subject);
      message.SetBody(send.Message);
      message.AddRecipient(send.RecipientAddress);
      //  High: Add attachments

      #if DEBUG
      ConfirmMessageCreation(send, message);
      #endif

      Logger.Log("Message created...\nSending message...", Verbose.LogEverything);
      result = message.Send();
   }

       else
          Logger.Log("There was a problem creating the email.", Verbose.LogImportant);
}
```

The actual cpp that sends the message follows:

```
BOOL MessageSend(CMAPIMessage* pMessage)
{
    return pMessage->Send();
}
```

...

```
BOOL CMAPIMessage::Send()
{
    HRESULT result = Message()->SubmitMessage(0);

    if(Message() && result==S_OK) 
    {
        Close();
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Even though I am properly logged in and can check or delete messages, I get an E_ACCESSDENIED error when calling Send(). Any insight into this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you set any sender related properties?

Comment: Just what is above. I set the sender name and email address.

Comment: Does it work if you do not add any sender related properties? Try to save the message (call SaveChanges instead of SubmitMessage), then look at it in OUtlookSpy (click IMEssage) and tr yt osubmti it by clicking SubmitMessage. If that does nto work, try to remove sender related properties. Are all recipients resolved (have PR_ENTRYID)?

Comment: @Dimitry, I removed the sender information, and it sent. You are a wonderful person! thank you so much. Please set an answer, and I will give you credit. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sender related properties need to be removed.